Is there a common mechanism that gives rise to spatial and time dilation in both Einstein's STR and GTR?
In both General and Special Relativity a body experiences both time and spatial dilation.  For example, as a particle approaches C it experiences dilations in time and space.  For a particle approaching the event horizon of a black hole it also experiences dilations in time and space.  Is there a common mechanism between these to events and in what term in STR and GTR does this mechanism arise?

What is spatial dilation?

@Amit Probably a reference to length contraction - it’s an intuitive term if not very commonly used and somewhat incorrect (contraction and dilation usually refer to opposite things).

@controlgroup It's not intuitive at all because dilation is the opposite of contraction

Haha yeah, well… the meaning eventually got across anyway.

What does "experiences" mean here?

I would also guess probably proper time/velocity vs. coordinate time/velocity… it should be made clearer, though.

A zero Ricci tensor in vacuum defines spacetime as an incompressible fluid whose 4D volume cannot change. As a result, in vacuum, the time dilation always equals in magnitude to the length contraction in either SR or GR.

The "T" is gauche.  "GR" and "SR" are preferred for Einstein's theories of special and general relativity, respectively.

In SR, time dilation is caused by your motion through space. In GR time dilation is caused by the motion of space through you.

Time dilation - not independent to SR or GR - is consequent entirely from the geometry of spacetime.
Consider the Minkowski metric, a.k.a. flat spacetime:
$$c^2\mathrm{d}\tau^2=c^2 \mathrm{d} t^2-\mathrm{d} x^2-\mathrm{d} y^2-\mathrm{d} z^2.$$
Evidently, $\gamma=\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}}}$ - when your coordinate velocity $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ goes up, the Lorentz factor goes up. This is usually called kinematic/kinetic time dilation because it’s a result of your motion in a particular frame.
Consider also the Schwarzschild metric, specifically one where you are not moving (in the privileged frame, i.e. the frame of the black hole being described):
$$c^2\mathrm{d}\tau^2=\left(1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}\right)c^2\mathrm{d}t^2.$$
Easily, you see that $\gamma=\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}\tau}=\sqrt{1-\frac{2GM}{rc^2}}$. We’re not moving in this case, so I dropped the spatial part of the metric because we’re at rest here, but the result is the same - a Lorentz factor dependent on certain things. This specific instance of that effect is usually known as gravitational time dilation.
In both cases the nontrivial Lorentz factor is entirely due to the geometry of spacetime. You can also do the same derivation to tell what the Lorentz factor is in curved spacetime while moving - I didn’t consider that case but it’s one you could consider nonetheless. What we see is that SR time dilation and GR time dilation have the same origin in the geometry of spacetime.

Snap! We must have been reading each other's minds when we typed our first sentences!

Answers posted less than two minutes apart too - we must share a braincell somewhere! Funny times.

The common mechanism is the geometry of spacetime. The elapsed time between a pair of events depends on geometric factors, such as whether they occur in the same place or two different places, whether the path through spacetime between them is straight or not, and the extent to which the local spacetime is curved.
